# iPhone - Flip Array and order NSOperationsQueue or ASINetworkQueue with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, asihttprequest

I was working on a project that needs to download data in order and append all the data. In order to solve this problem, I decided to use queues (NSOperationsQueue or ASINetworkQueue). Unfortunately, the order was reversed because ASINetworkQueue and NSOperationQueue are stacks. I've tried flipping the array, but the appended audio stream goes in the order of 2 (request), 1 request, and 3 request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NSOperationQueue isn't a stack, it's a queue. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else, like the fact that network operations are asynchronous and won't come back in any well-defined order unless you force them to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you can't parallelize your operations so i suggest the following solution:

- use the setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: method with parameter 1 (NSOperationQueue will be executed in the order they were added)
- use the synchronous requests of the ASIHTTPRequest framework

Comment: Hi,

Synchronous methods won't work for me as the UI needs to be free. Also, I have already set the maxconcurrentoperationcount to 1. 

Now, however, it seems as though the data appended is overlaid with  the other data.

Comment: You can leave the main thread to the UI and have a background thread doing synchronous work. If you could post more details about your code (maybe some samples of the critical parts), it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I eventually got this to work by just using gcd to run the synchronous operation in background.